# Read/Write permission for a program run with subprocess?

Tags: django, permissions, subprocess

I've got a Django app, which calls a program using `subprocess.call()`. This program creates a couple of files, which I then use back in my app. The problem is the program doesn't seem to have permission to create files. I also tried calls like `subprocess.call(['mkdir','/tmp/myapp'])` but the directory was not created. What do I need to do?

This is just with my dev server at the moment, which I invoke with

```
sudo python manage.py runserver 0.0.0.0:8080
```

I can run the command from the terminal manually fine.

I can also use subprocess to `touch` the files, which it does fine, but when it runs the program that accesses the files itself, that program throws an error because it cannot.

Comment: Why are you running your server using sudo?

Comment: @César Because I did the first time (by mistake it seems), and since then starting without sudo caused problems (because it couldn't read it's own log files). Have now sorted, thanks! Sadly it doesn't solve this problem...

Comment: Maybe this [What permissions are required for subprocess.Popen?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2066068/what-permissions-are-required-for-subprocess-popen) or this [running a command as a super user from a python script](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/567542/running-a-command-as-a-super-user-from-a-python-script) can help

Comment: If you're just messing with the filesystem, have python to do it rather than spawning processes: http://docs.python.org/2/library/os.html#os.mkdir

Answer (score 1):

The /tmp/myapp directory needs to be created first. If your view function in Django doesn't show you an error it means that you are not catching it properly. 
Try something like this:

```
response = HttpResponse()
calltxt = subprocess.call(['mkdir','/tmp/myapp'])
response.content = calltxt
return response
```

Append the function to your urls.py and load it in the browser.
0 means the command executed successfully, 1 means error (this is similar to the $! variable in Bash).

I think it's not the case but if your Django app is deployed in the Web Server the user that creates files and executes commands out of the Python environment is the one that owns the web server daemon. For instance www-data in Apache. 
Thus, it is needed to change permissions for this user also in order to write and execute commands out of their normal scope.